# Fluent Nhibernate - inserts the parent but not the childs

Tags: c#, oracle, fluent-nhibernate

im using fluent nhibernate and  im having trouble saving an entiity.

So, I have Books table, Book_Types table and a join table between them - TypeInBook table, since book can have many books, so its a many to many connection.

so in my the book model i have ofcurse a lise of book types:

```
public virtual IList<BookType> BookTypes {get; set; }
```

here is how i map it :

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.BookTypes).Table("TYPES_IN_BOOKS").ParentKeyColumn("BOOK_TYPE_ID").ChildKeyColumn("BOOK_ID").Inverse();
```

Now, if I'm removing the inverse it tries (for my understanding) to add the children first, but it cant because the parent has not been added and therefore cant make the constraint (to something that doesnt exists).
And when I'm adding the inverse, it inserts the parent but not the children.

Comment: Have you tried Cascade.InsertOrUpdate()?

Comment: `inverse` is incorrect here since i doubt that BookType has a Books collection. Please post the error which is thrown without `inverse`